# logback rewrite xml configuration programmatically

Tags: java, logback

Is there a way to add a dynamically created logback logger to its xml configuration file in order to keep the configuration upon application restarts?

In my code i do the following:

```
public static Logger createLogger(LoggingConfiguration configuration) { 

String appenderName = configuration.getName();
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
Logger _logger = context.exists(appenderName);

if(_logger == null) {
    logger.info("AcceptanceLogger: configured logger does not exists. Create new one with name: [{}] ", configuration.getName());
    String appenderPath = configuration.getPath();

    PatternLayoutEncoder ple = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
    ple.setPattern(getAppenderPatternByLogType(configuration));
    ple.setContext(context);
    ple.start();

    RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent> rollingFileAppender = new RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
    rollingFileAppender.setName(appenderName);
    rollingFileAppender.setFile(generateFileName(appenderName, appenderPath));
    rollingFileAppender.setEncoder(ple);
    rollingFileAppender.setContext(context);
    rollingFileAppender.setImmediateFlush(true);
    

    TimeBasedRollingPolicy<ILoggingEvent> rollingPolicy = new TimeBasedRollingPolicy<ILoggingEvent>();
    rollingPolicy.setFileNamePattern(generateFileName(appenderName + LoggerConstant.DAILY_ROLLING_POLICY , appenderPath));
    rollingPolicy.setContext(context);
    rollingPolicy.setParent(rollingFileAppender);
    rollingPolicy.start();
    
    rollingFileAppender.setRollingPolicy(rollingPolicy);
    rollingFileAppender.start();        
    
   _logger = context.getLogger(appenderName);
   _logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
   _logger.setAdditive(false);
   _logger.addAppender(rollingFileAppender);
}
return _logger;
}
```

With this approach everything works fine on application side but, upon application restarts the logger no longer exists.

My idea was to add it to the xml configuration but i cannot find any way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize as per your need. Sample logback file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><included>
<appender name="AzureWebServices" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>DEBUG</level>
    </filter>
    <File>${logfile.Directory}/webservices/AzureWebService-${logfile.NamePostfix}.log</File>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <FileNamePattern>${logfile.Directory}/webservices/AzureWebService-${logfile.NamePostfix}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>
            [%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z}] %-5level ${HostName} ${InstallationID} ${ServerName} [%mdc{requestsite}] [%mdc{requestapplication}] %logger [%marker] [%mdc{request.type}] [%mdc{session.id}] [%mdc{request.uuid}] &quot;%thread&quot; %msg %ex%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender> 

<logger name="com.adapter.azureservices" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="AzureWebServices" />
</logger>

<logger name="AzureWebService" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="AzureWebServices" />
</logger>
```

Comment: this answer is out of scope. I perfectly know how to configure logback via xml. What i'm asking is how can i produce the xml file from the java code which, is quite different from what you are proposing.